# Resources for finding organised treks based on specific criteria

Tags: trekking, preparation, resources

I'm unsure where to go this summer/autumn.  Among my options would be to join an organised trek somewhere I wouldn't (currently) want to go independently (such as for experience, language, cultural, or political reasons).

Are there any targeted search engines where I can search for organised treks based on criteria such as location, length, difficulty, group size, language, price, and other characteristics?  For example, one could search for "challenging tent trekking 7-20 days in northern Russia in August or September with group speaking English, Dutch, German, or Swedish", or "easy-moderate Dutch-speaking hostel to hostel trekking of any duration with luggage transport in northern Spain between September and December".  I'm aware of quite a few (commercial or not-for-profit) organisations selling trekking vacations but the market does not appear very transparent.  Google Search may miss quite a lot.

Note that this is different from "how to look for a trail buddy"; this question is about organised treks sold by commercial companies or not-for-profit organisations.

Answer (score 3):

[AllTrails.com](https://www.alltrails.com/?ref=header) would probably be helpful. You can search based on location, difficulty, length, etc.

Hope this helps.